# Exporting .mat file with character matrix to .csv in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a matrix with 3360x60 character. I would like to export this data into csv file. However, it converts each character into one column.

If I apply below function, it will convert them each row with , in it.

```
csvwrite('bin_m.csv', matrix);
```

For example, if I have one row value of 1101....111 this number is now converted into 1,1,0,1, ...1,1,1.

Here's a sample value stored in matrix.

```
'000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000110000000'
```

Any other suggestion?

Comment: yes it is only binar1 numbers

Comment: Are you saying you want to store data as comma separated values (csv) file, but not actually separate your values with commas?  Can you show what you want the first one or two lines to look like in your output file?

Answer (score 0):

Creating sample data:

```
matrix = reshape('110011101010101001',3,[])
```

```
matrix =

  3×6 char array

    '101010'
    '110100'
    '011011'
```

Convert your matrix to cell array of character vectors using [**`cellstr`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html) and use [**`fprintf`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) to write the data.

```
matrixcell=cellstr(matrix);             %Converting to cell array 
fileID = fopen('bin_m.csv','wt');       %Opening/Creating the file for writing
fprintf(fileID,'%s\n', matrixcell{:});  %Writing the data; (notice the `{:}` )
fclose(fileID);                         %Closing the opened file
```

**Output:**

[image]